# Help to understand manipulations on limits and integrals - $\int_a^b \! c \, \mathrm{d}x=c(b-a)$

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, definite-integrals

I'm reading this proof from [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/ProofIntProp.aspx):
[image]

and I don't understand how to reach $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}c \right)\frac{b-a}{n}$$

Specifically, why are we allowed to take out $\frac{b-a}{n}$ from the summation? It seems that we are treating it as a constant but I don't think it is a constant since the denominator, $n$, is part of the summation.

Then I tried proving this myself:

> $$\begin{align} 
> \int_a^b \! c \, \mathrm{d}x &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}c\frac{b-a}{n}\\
> &= \lim_{n \to \infty} c \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{b-a}{n}\\
> &= \lim_{n \to \infty} c(b-a) \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n} \\
> &= c(b-a) \lim_{n \to \infty}  \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}
> \end{align}$$

I need $\lim_{n \to \infty}  \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}$ to be equal to $1$ to complete the proof, but it is not, is it?

What did I do wrong?

Comment: the function is a constant function so we have always here, $f(x_i^*)=c$.

Comment: okay, I get that. But why don't we also sum $\frac{b-a}{n}$?

Comment: @manu: It can move out of the sum because we had assumed that the length of sub-intervals be $\frac{b-a}n$ and it is indeed free of $i$

Comment: @B.S. oh okay. I see it now. Thank you. Would you like to post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You confused $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}$ with $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}$. Actually,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n 1 = \frac{1}{n}\cdot n =1.
$$

Answer (score 0):

This is something that occurs in summations often. One component in the development of the proof is the series 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} c$$. 
Now, with care, this is the same as the following:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{1} c &= c \\
\sum_{k=1}^{3} c &= c + c + c = 3c \\
\sum_{k=1}^{5} c &= c + c + c + c + c = 5c
\end{align} 
and so on. This leads to
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} c = c \,n.$$

The proof outlined then becomes
\begin{align} 
\int_a^b \! c \, \mathrm{d}x &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}c\frac{b-a}{n}\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} c \right) \, \frac{b-a}{n}\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{c \, n \, (b-a)}{n} \\
&= c(b-a) \lim_{n \to \infty} \{ 1 \} \\
&= c \, (b-a)
\end{align}